# Django 'TestForm' object has no attribute 'fields'

Tags: python, django, forms, dropdownbox

I'm using django:

I'm trying to pass a list of tuples from `views.py` to a dropdown box form but I get this attribute error

`forms.py`

```
import logging                                                                   

from django import forms                                                         

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)                                                

class TestForm(forms.Form):                                                    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                         
        testlist = kwargs.pop('testlist',None)                               
        log.info(regionlist)                                                     
        self.fields['testlist'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=testlist)        
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`views.py`

```
form = forms.RegionForm(regionlist=data)
```

Am I using the right method to pass variables between `views.py` and `forms.py`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to call `super` first, so that the superclass sets up the `fields` attribute.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                         
    testlist = kwargs.pop('testlist', None)
    log.info(regionlist)
    super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['testlist'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=testlist)
```

Comment: This is a GREAT answer that I had to dig to find so I'm going to add some keywords to make it easier to find. 

To dynamically add fields to a form regardless of the form class parent (in other words, NO MODEL FORM and no need for save), this ^ allows the option to **pass in named arguments** to make **dynamic fields**. After form is instantiated (super) you can call any class functions on those variables passed in and set them to self.fields dynamically. Thus you have dynamic fields in a form that can be passed in at instantiation time.

Comment: This answer solved a form reload problem I had where the dynamic fields kept the choices from the last run. I was querying elastic search for filters that would be given back dynamically and would change, the data and the form.fields and form.base_fields were being set correctly but the cache of the form didn't seem to be When it would render it would have the old fields and wouldn't update right though I passed in the filters (new dynamic fields) to the form. 

Now that I pass in the dynamic fields this way and recreate the form with the request and filters it works great! Thank you Daniel.